# Deployer sometimes locks the table after updating it

Tags: dxa, web8.5, deployer, deployer-extension

In our DXA application we have a deployer extension to save page URLs to a custom table on page publish.
The deployer sometimes locks the table ABC_TEST_PRODUCT and to unlock it we need to restart the deployer worker services. When the table are locked the integration layer can´t read from it.

Is there a way to fix it. We are not sure what could be the possible issue and where to start looking.

Any information would be really helpful. TIA.

Comment: Where does the deployer extension come from? I'd think your first avenue of exploration would be to talk to whoever made it.